# Are there any difference using scores or probabilities for roc_auc_score and precision_recall_curve functions?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc, precision-recall, threshold

I'm working with a GNN model for link prediction and using `precision_recall_curve` and `roc_auc_score` from the `sklearn.metrics` functions. For the GNN definition and use, I'm using [Pytorch geometric](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

The last layer of my GNN is a dot product between aggregated node features, which I'm considering as the score.

It means I have a final tensor with a score (float value) indicating if I have a link (class 1) or not (class 0) together with a `ground_truths` containing the actual classes (0 or 1). Assuming that my model is well-defined, I'm using the following code for evaluation:

```
# val_loader is an iterator for the validation dataset, and the model is the actual GNN

from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve

preds = []
ground_truths = []
for sampled_data in tqdm.tqdm(val_loader):
    with torch.no_grad():
        sampled_data.to(device)
        preds.append(model(sampled_data))
        ground_truths.append(sampled_data[node1, link, node2].edge_label)

pred = torch.cat(preds, dim=0).cpu().numpy()
ground_truth = torch.cat(ground_truths, dim=0).cpu().numpy()

# Metric 1 - ROC
auc = roc_auc_score(ground_truth, pred)
print(f"Validation ROC_AUC: {auc:.4f}")

# Metric 2 - Precision Recall
precision, recall, _ = precision_recall_curve(ground_truth, (torch.sigmoid(torch.from_numpy(pred))))
pr_auc = area_curve (recall, precision)
```

After this code, I'm using these values to calculate the optimal threshold for predicting the missing links in my graph.

It's possible to see in the code that for `roc_auc_score,` I'm using the scores (not sure if I can call them the logits, but I guess so) returned by my model (`preds` variable), while in `precision_recall_curve` I'm using the probabilities instead, passing by a `sigmoid` function.

Looking at the functions documentation ([1](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html) and [2](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html)), I understand that I can use them interchangeably.

**My question is**: Is this assumption correct independently of my GNN model? If so, how this works since they are completely different values (the score is a float tensor with no apparent meaning while the probabilities are actual values between 0 and 1 that I can consider as probabilities of being the class 1 - an existent link)?

An extra problem is: Is there any difference when calculating the optimal threshold if I used scores or probabilities, or is there an equivalence too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sigmoid is a strictly increasing function, so the ordering of the scores is the same as that of the "probabilities"*.  Both the ROC curve and the precision-recall curve only care about the ordering of scores, so no, there will be no difference between the curves generated by the two versions.

With thresholds, there's a little more wiggle room, since between any two score values there are infinitely many thresholds that produce the same hard classifier and the same point in ROC (resp. PR) space.  But the score thresholds correspond bijectively to probability thresholds (just the sigmoid and its inverse), so any optimal threshold for one will have a corresponding optimal threshold in the other.  In many packages, the midpoint between consecutive unique score values gets used as the threshold between them, and *those* won't quite correspond: $\sigma((a+b)/2) \neq (\sigma(a)+\sigma(b))/2$.

*depending on your network architecture, these might not be well-calibrated probabilities

Comment: Maybe I should create another question for this one, but to take the opportunity, if this is something possible to be answered in a comment:

If my area under the ROC curve is higher than 0.6, can I consider my probabilities "well-calibrated," or am I mixing up some concepts here?

Comment: A terrible classifier can still be well-calibrated; e.g. always predicting the proportion of the positive class is well-calibrated.